# How to create Recurring of Alarm in Android After taking user input?

Tags: android, android-alarms

I am an android developer.I am making an application in which I have to take user input like
8:00,9:00,10:00 etc and I have to set alarm for 20 or 30 days for each time user enter .A user can enter two or three or any times the timings.I know there is a function

`alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC,System.currentTimeMillis()+timeinminutes*60*1000,30*1000,  pintent);`

But I have to set the alarm for ever or days entered by user .So can any body tell me .How can I do this .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following code help you,firstWake the app will run at very fast time,you can specify as your requirements

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

long interval = android.text.format.DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS*20;//or 30

long firstWake = System.currentTimeMillis() ;

am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC,firstWake, interval, pendingIntent);
```

Comment: Hi Nitin,the above will work for every 20 or 30 days,give some clarity,you asked it for 20 or 30 days.is not it?,all you need to develop a better logic only.

Comment: do you mean that it work every day upto 20 days?If it is then implement the logic for 1 day(instead of 20 days) and put a count variable store it in SharedPreference class(see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html),whenever this variable count reaches 20, stop to call that alaram method.

Comment: But I think it will not work for me.Because user can enter timing any times.So how much count variable I should use how would i know .

Comment: you want alarm for every day(up to 20 days?) at the time given by user input?did u get my point?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use another nonrepeating alarm for 20 or 30 days that stops repeating alarms.