# How to restrict alarm from reoccurring after particular days in android?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I am an android developer I have asked this question before But may be I was not able to explain it more I want set repeating alarm with day interval .How can i restrict it from recurring after some days for example 15days can any body help me .
following was my first question please check it
[How to create Recurring of Alarm in Android After taking user input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6591592/how-to-create-recurring-of-alarm-in-android-after-taking-user-input)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't know how well catch this, but let me give you a tip, make a class which has static method for `startimg` alarm, and use `set()` method of `alarmManager` to set interval and so on. and in `Broadcaste reciever` in its `onRecieve()` method call the static method again. but in any of these classes declare a static field which is `incremented each time onRecieve()` method is called. and before `setting the alarm put an if() condition to check its not 15`. and for pendingIntent use this flag `PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT`.

**when user enters his days do this**

```
int temp = /*days entered by user*/;//initialize tis variable with user entered value

if(temp != 0){
    private static long interval = android.text.format.DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS*temp;
}


if(System.getCurrentTimeInMillis()<interval){
//set Your Alarm.
}
```

Comment: Sir please check my previous question

Comment: Sir can please help me I wants to have a chat with you

Comment: Sir I think this code can set alarm for one time for example 9:00 every day but if user wants to set alarm for example at 9:00 ,10:00 and 24 times I know one object alarm manager can set one alarm at a time so what should i do

Comment: when user enters some value call this method to set Alarm. and pass the value he entered. and initialize it to the temp variable i told. rest will work fine.

Comment: ntc sir can you come in discussion room may be you can help me http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2349/discussion-between-nitin-and-umesh

Answer (score 1):

1. device a repeating alarm not by using the 'setRepeating' method but by rescheduling the alarm every time the alarm fires by using the 'set' method.
2. Use Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH - 'day of month the alarm was first scheduled' to find out the number of days elapsed.
3. if your condition is satisfied, use alarm.cancel(pendingIntent) method to cancel the alarm.

Comment: use the month also to be sure of the number of days elapsed.

Comment: Sir please check my previous question

Comment: i read your question and i must say, my answer remains the same. you may add n alarms for n timings, if that makes your life easy.

Comment: Sir how i can generate set function at run time? because user can enter many time

Comment: Whenever the user puts in a new value and saves his settings, reset the alarm. As i said the answer is the same no matter how many times the user sets. suppose he sets 10 'times' eg: time[10], your app should be able to reschedule itself to the next 'time[i]' the user has set. after finishing all the task for the day, the alarm will be scheduled to the first time on the next day. eg: time[0].

Comment: @Umesh let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2349/discussion-between-nitin-and-umesh)